# Dart, I can't return anything inside of a foreach

Tags: flutter, dart

So, as the title says, I can't return anything inside of a foreach in this function. It is not a problem of the conditional because I have tried it and it works, I can enter in it, I can even print a text, but I cannot return anything, which is weird, maybe forEach in dart works different than I know?

```
Future<String> getEnrollment(idU) async {
  final querySnapshot =
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Enrollment').get();

  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
    if (doc['infoCar']['idUser'] == idU) {
      return doc.id; // I can't return this one.
    }
  });

  return null;
}
```

Comment: If you can simplify your code and try to duplicate the same problem in https://dartpad.dev/ Then you will have a very popular question.

Comment: I can't see how to do it in dartpad since I'm using `FirebaseFirestore`, the thing is, that I can't return `doc.dic`  even when the `if` statement works perfectly,

Comment: `forEach` takes in a new function - so the return scope changes to that internal function. Obviously, you can't return the outer function by returning in an inner function - you have to break the scope. I'd strongly suggest using `firstWhere()` and return your condition, whichs gives you the found doc index. `var foundDocIndex = querySnapshot.docs.firstWhere((doc) => doc['infoCar']['idUser'] == idU)`

Comment: can you mock a result object like https://dartpad.dev/22e53cd67ca6a2ddbe4b5f610edad373

Comment: @cemkaan Sorry I wasn't sure! however, the problem was solved, thanks!

Comment: @pascalpuetz I can see the problem now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem with Dart. You are facing this problem because the function inside of `forEach` is a callback function. So, when your return inside that function, you are returning `doc.id` from that function, instead of  `getEnrollment()` function. You can see the same behavior in other languages that support callbacks e.g JavaScript.

However, you can solve your problem using `firstWhere()` instead.

```
 Future<String> getEnrollment(idU) async {
    final querySnapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Enrollment').get();

    final enrollment = querySnapshot.docs.firstWhere(
      (doc) => doc['infoCar']['idUser'] == idU,
      orElse: () => null,
    );

    if (enrollment == null) return null;
    return enrollment.id;
  }
```

Note: `orElse` runs when the `firstWhere` doesn't return true for any item in the list. Here we are returning `null` in that case.

Comment: Works perfectly and I can see the problem now, it feels like LINQ in C# but it's kinda more complicated for me. Also, where do you recommend me looking at the documentation on callback functions? Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You can learn more about `firstWhere` here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `iterable.forEach...` with `for (e in iterable) { ... if ([something about e]) { return [something] } }`

That'll work because the return now means the enclosing subroutine.